# VS2008 Smart Device project to work with TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I would like to check in my Visual Studio 2008 project (Smart Device Project) into TFS 2010.

Last time, I tried this grueling task, there were so many quirks and plugins and at the end of the day, it still failed to detect a change in the file....

so, at this day and age, is it possible to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May be the response is too late... but...

You will need to get VS2008 installed on the build agent server. Most of the job is done at this point.

I have managed to get TFS 2010 to deploy the unit tests in a device too.

I think general google search will help.